# Coldfusion getHttpRequestData breaks my SOAP calls

Tags: web-services, soap, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm running Coldfusion 9.  I have some web services that are called via SOAP calls.  We have a load balancer that forwards the clients IP address in the header of each request.  We need to get that IP address but if we use the function getHttpRequestData to get the header when making a SOAP call, it returns "org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file."  If I comment out that function, it returns correctly, but with our load balancer's IP address.  My question is: hasn't this been fixed yet?  I've heard that this problem existed in CF8.  Is there any other way to get the request headers if this bug can't be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using getHttpRequestData function, I used getPageContext().getRequest().getHeader("X-Forwarded-For") to retrieve my X-Forwarded-For header and this doesn't break the SOAP request

Comment: Good job. Feel free to mark your response as the answer then.

Comment: Eerie... your question reads exactly like what I'm experiencing. Load balancer, need to get the IP, start using getHttpRequestData, web services start failing inexplicably. Good catch.